# Trying to figure out how to make a list in excel from an input in another cell

Tags: excel

Okay so say I have a list of emails (yet to be inputted)

When an email is input in a1, I want that SAME email, to show up in a2, then when I change the input the next email shows in A3, etc.

Something like

```
Input 
Jon.doe@email.com into A1

The list would maybe start at B1 and say
Jon.doe@email.com

Then we input
Jason.doe@email.com into A1
The list would then add an entry at B2 
B2 would say Jason.doe@email.com (keeping both emails and being inputted in one place)
```

Any ideas?

After that I just have to add a whitespace validation (something like A1:trim) - the final list (b1 , b2, etc) would have the validated entries or entries with no whitespace.

Also this has to be able to be put online where multiple people may add entries , have them validated and added to the list.

Comment: Doable with VBA - look into the Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: No way it can be done with just excel ? I've never used VBA , its sort of a favor to a friend (never really worked with excel tables much either , I usually code)

Comment: If you code then this should be easy with VBA. Otherwise there is no way that I know of. **EDIT:** well VBA and online don't go together, so you may need a different solution.

Comment: Okay well I guess I'll keep looking , thank you!

Comment: Not sure for this task, but one option may be the [Excel JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview).